# Calling functions with various parameters using user input

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script that runs a bunch a function that are specified as a dictionary in JSON (this is user input). Here is what the JSON file contains:

```
{
"tests_to_run": {"find_holes": [],
                 "is_greater": [1.2]
                 }
}
```

`find_holes` and `is_greater` are two functions that I have written, the first taking 0, the second 1 parameter. The idea is to specify these parameters in the list associated with the function key in the JSON dictionary.

I am currently using this dictionary as follows:

```
functions_dict = {"find_holes": val.find_holes,
                 "is_monotonic": val.is_monotonic}

def run_functions(dict_tests_to_run):
    for func, params in dict_tests_to_run.iteritems():
        if params==[]:
            functions_dict[func](time_series)
        if len(params)==1:
            functions_dict[func](time_series, params[0])
```

It seems a bit awkward to manually check for the length of the parameters, in particular since I am going to have to extend the loop to accomodate functions with up to at least 4 parameters. Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `*` operator to expand your list into function parameters.  For example,

```
f(1,2,3)
```

is equivalent to:

```
a=[1,2,3]
f(*a)
```